# How to permanently disconnect Visual Studio solution from source control

Tags: visual-studio-2012, source-control-bindings

I have a Visual Studio 2012 solution with a few projects in it. Every time i open the solution file i get the message:

> The mappings for the solution could not be found.
>   The active solution
>   has been temporarily disconnected from source control because the
>   server is unavailable.  To attempt to reconnect to source control,
>   close and then re-open the solution when the server is available.  If
>   you want to connect this solution to another server, use the Change
>   Source Control dialog.

**What i want to do is PERMANENTLY remove any mention of source control, but no luck so far.**

### Here is what i have tried so far

1. Deleted the usual suspect files, such as suo, mssccprj.scc, vssver.scc, etc
2. Manually opened every project file (.vbproj, .csproj) and deleted the four lines
       SccProjectName = "etc"
       SccAuxPath = "etc"
       SccLocalPath = "etc"
       SccProvider = "etc"
3. Ditto for the solution file
4. Noticed that there is a web site project (rather than web application project) in my solution, but being a website project i cannot perform step 2. on it.
5. Checked the dialog "File/Source Control/Advanced/Change Source Control" and noticed that every listed Solution/Projects have NO SERVER, NO BINDING, Status is "Not Controlled"

As well as the message described above (has been temporarily disconnected etc), the following 4 lines always get ADDED BACK to the solution file, no matter how many times i've deleted them.

> SccProjectName = "MyApp"
> SccAuxPath = "https://some.annoying.domain.com/VaultService"
> SccLocalPath = "4~89a6b376-099d-49a7-801a-2ba7adb0e268"
> SccProvider = "SourceGear Vault Visual Studio 2005 Client:{7BE9CE03-56BF-4682-9C06-78C68B134B30}"

These 4 lines are within the section that describes the website project.

> Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "MyApp",
>   "`http://localhost/MyApp`",
>   "{A5301379-1092-419E-9B03-E37E16E0A8B2}"
>   ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject

I strongly suspect it is the website project that is screwing it up. But where is the website project holding the source control info?

### Further info:

I have already searched all file contents for the string "some.annoying.domain.com" but came up with nothing of significance (found in OTHER solutions, not this particular solution).

The solution appears to have been originally created in VS2010 (where the previous dev obviously used SourceGear's Vault product).

** NB: I could try to change the website proj to a web app proj, and see how it goes, but that's beside the point.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Change the source control plugin to None:

```
Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Plug-in Selection: None
```

And respond with `Yes` to the question if you want the sources to not be under source control.

Comment: Restart Visual Studio after you change the options under Tools menu and then It will ask you to permanently remove the bindings!

Comment: I can also confim this does the trick.   1) Set the plugin to none. 2) Restart VS   3) Re-open the solution and you'll be prompted to remove the bindings.  4) (optional) Set the plugin back to Team Foundation Services

Comment: More than 4 years later I think this answer is probably the correct one! (I left that job and no longer have access to that project/solution) - but a similar problem leads me back here ! and time to accept this answer.

Answer (score 3):

in addition to your previous actions try to delete contents of **C:\Users\[yourusername]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\[version]\Cache**

i hope it helps

Comment: The accepted answer did not accomplish what I wanted - it continued to ask every time I opened the solution if I would like to remove bindings. Deleting the contents of the cache folder is what worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

For step 2 (actually, I did this in the solution file, since my solution has no project files), try setting all values to blank:

- SccProjectName = ""
- SccAuxPath = ""
- SccLocalPath = ""
- SccProvider = ""